# Subdomain A-Record Change doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, dns

I have two different hosting packages. One that just holds all of the domains and the other one that holds a managed server. Over a week ago i created a subdomain to one of my domains. As soon as the domain was created i changed the a-record to point the subdomain to my server.

There is .htaccess file in the root of my server that is suppose to redirect the subdomain to the folder that contains the website. In that website folder there is another .htaccess file.

Here is the .htaccess file of the server root:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub.domain\.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1
```

And this is the .htaccess file within the folder for that subdomain:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.sub.domain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sub.domain.de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The issue i have now is that if i access the subdomain from my desktop pc everything works just fine. But if i try to access from my cellphone or a computer of a friend it gives me a Forbidden Error.

I am really lost when it comes to all of that. When i use an online service to show if the site is down or not it tells me that the site is working just fine. Does anybody have any idea where the problem is here???

Comment: I suspect this isn't related to your rewrites.  If your mover your computer to another network (like starbucks wifi or tethered to your phone data) does it also return a "Forbidden"

Comment: @Ray I haven't tested that. I think i will have a chance to try it out tomorrow.